# How to uninstall "USB Overdrive" via terminal without mouse?

Tags: uninstall, osx-lion

I installed [USB overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html) to my 10.7 Lion distribution. Unfortunately I can't move my mouse after that anymore.

In my Applications folder there is an application named "Uninstall USB Overdrive.app". Via <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> I can open it, but since I have no mouse, I can't select anything from the popup.

I also tried safe mode without success. So my question is: How can I uninstall this app by using the terminal?

Comment: I cant select anything using the tab key in the popup. There are 2 possibilities Quit or Uninstall. Quit is selected as standard. The only thing i can do is pushing enter and logically the dialog closes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Enable global keyboard access

See if you have "All controls" are enabled in *System Preferences → Keyboard & Mouse* (only on Leopard now, should be similar in Lion).

You will need to press the appropriate keyboard shortcut, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> to toggle this setting.

[image]

When enabled, you can navigate all dialogs with <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, selecting elements with <kbd>Space</kbd>. This should get you through the uninstallation.

---

#### Manually call the uninstallation script

Try this:

```
/Applications/Utilities/Uninstall\ USB\ Overdrive.app/Contents/Resources/rmusbo
```

This is what I believe should work instantly, as it is the only script there is in the Uninstallation app (I just downloaded the tool, version 3.0.1 and checked).

Comment: Thank you pretty much! You saved my day! Your first suggestion was just right. After that i was able to tab switch in the popup menu. After the uninstall process i rebooted and everything works fine now again, making me smile :D