# Magic Trackpad clicks and points, but doesn't scroll

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, scrolling, mac-mini, magic-trackpad

I just got a new-to-me Magic Trackpad, but after pairing it and adjusting the settings in System Preferences, I can't get it to do the two-finger scrolling gesture.

So far, I've uninstalled USB Overdrive, and the Microsoft Mouse plugin I installed previously. Even after a restart, the scrolling is still absent.

This is a Mac Mini running 10.6.8.

What's the best way to come at this from a systematic perspective?

Comment: Did you remove the USB Overdrive kernel extension as well? I had the same issue because I hadn't.

Comment: Pretty sure, yes. I used the command-line directions from here: http://superuser.com/questions/318983/how-to-uninstall-usb-overdrive-via-terminal-without-mouse, which were to use this one-liner: /Applications/Utilities/Uninstall\ USB\ Overdrive.app/Contents/Resources/rmusbo

Comment: As another data point, I did try downloading the Magic Trackpad and Multitouch Update from Apple's support site. The installer reports that I don't need to install it.

Comment: Then check for `MicrosoftMouse.kext` and other kernel extensions. Some are listed at [usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Support.html](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Support.html)

Comment: I found MicrosoftMouse.kext and removed it. I also looked at the list on the USB Overdrive support page, but found none of the ones listed. Rebooted, but the Magic Trackpad still fails to scroll.

Comment: Success! It turned out that the USB Overdrive extension was NOT removed from /System/Library/Extensions. Deleting it and rebooting has enabled scrolling!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on the comments the issue was solved by deleting `/System/Library/Extensions/USBOverdrive.kext`. Other extensions listed at the [USB Overdrive support page](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Support.html):

```
KensingtonMouseDriver.kext
LCC.kext
LogitechHIDDevices.kext
LogitechUnifying.kext
LogitechUSBHIDevices.kext
MacallyKMDriver.kext
MicrosoftKeyboard.kext
MicrosoftMouse.kext
SteerMouse.kext
```

If any of them exists, try running the original uninstallers of the drivers.

Comment: Right. I don't know what the command-line-triggered uninstaller did, but it didn't uninstall the USBOverdrive.kext. Once it was deleted manually (dragged to trash) and I rebooted, all was well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd perform these steps to help isolate the issue:

- Fresh batteries (especially if you are less than 50%) - just for testing
- Reboot the mac in safe mode to disable all third party and non-essential Apple kernel extensions
- Download and apply any combo updater newer than 10.6.5 (and equal to or higher than your current OS)
- Make a new user account (a long shot - but worth it)
- Pair the trackpad with another Mac that's running 10.6.5 or later

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with USB overdrive 3.0.1, updating to 3.0.2 fixed this for me.

See the changelog:

```
New in version 3.0.2:
    -No longer tries to handle Magic Trackpad and Magic Mouse
    -Updated Login Items and Installer code to support Mountain Lion
    -Added code signature for Mountain Lion installation
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my Magic Trackpad 2 scroll to function by going into `Universal Access -> Mouse And Trackpad -> Trackpad options -> Scroll`and enable it if not already enabled.

See screenshot (in Dutch: `Systeem vookeuren -> Toegankelijkheid -> Muis en trackpad -> Trackpadopties... -> Scrol`)

[image: Screenshot]

System setup:
iMac Late 2009 with Bluetooth 2.0 (not 4.0)
MTP2 connected with Bluetooth
OS X El Capitan (10.11.2)